# Can drag top panel in a touch screen device

Tags: release-freya, touchscreen

I am using Acer ICONIA TAB W500P and my problem is that I can drag the top panel by touching and dragging it.

(I used my fingers to drag it)

[image: dragging the top panel with my fingers (not mouse)]

I can't move it with my mouse and I can't reset it unless if I run `pkill wingpanel` in the terminal. It annoys me every time I accidentally drag it and I need to reset it again with the command.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, which will be fixed in the next release of elementary OS: https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel/+bug/1432512